# How to find shortcut file used to start a process using Powershell

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, process, windows-10

I have a google chrome process running for which I can get information using the following commands:

```
get-process chrome | select name, starttime
wmic process where "name='chrome.exe'" get CommandLine
```

The commands give information about which file was executed i.e.

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

However, there are few shortcuts to google chrome eg Taskbar shortcut, Start menu shortcut, and maybe others that I don't know.

How can I find which shortcut was used to launch google chrome?

Comment: "How can I find which shortcut was used to launch google chrome?" - you can't, the process itself won't "know"

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Is there any way to know? Maybe which shortcuts/files were recently opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer to the question that which shortcut file was run however I am able to get my purpose fulfilled by getting the list of all the shortcut files using the following command and making required changes to all the relevant shortcuts.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_ShortcutFile | select Name, FileName, CreationDate, LastAccessed, Drive, Path,  FileType
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Like this?

For TaskBar Shortcut:

```
PS> (gci C:\Users\[USERID]\AppData -Filter "*Chrome.lnk" -Recurse).LastAccessTime

Sunday, May 9, 2021 10:11:25 AM2
```

For Desktop Shortcut:

```
PS> (gci C:\Users\[USERID]\Desktop -Filter "*Chrome.lnk" -Recurse).LastAccessTime

Monday, May 10, 2021 10:59:12 AM2
```

For more info:

```
PS> gci C:\Users\[USERID]\AppData -Filter "*Chrome*.lnk" -Recurse | Select LastAccessTime, FullName

LastAccessTime       FullName                                                                                               
--------------       --------                                                                                               
5/9/2021 10:11:25 AM C:\Users\[USERID]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Google Chrome.lnk              
5/9/2021 10:11:25 AM C:\Users\[USERID]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Chrome Apps\VNC® Viewer for Goo...
```

Once you have the times you can check against the current time to select which if you get multiple answers.

HTH